# Individual of type Dict in DEAP framework

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, genetic-algorithm, deap

Is there any way to get individual of type `dict` working in GA operators (Crossovers, mutate, select and evaluate)?

I used cxOnePoint to crossover, but I got an error of `TypeErro: Unhashable type: 'slice'`.
Then, I tried using `cxOrdered`, but there is no luck at all. I got `key error` in this case.

Comment: Could you show an example of what you tried? What codes gives the error?